# Operations with return values in C

Tags: c, if-statement, return, return-value

I'm new to C and trying to write a super basic program that compares 3 numbers and returns the biggest.

But when I try to print some text with if functions, it skips 2 if and goes to else. I might told it more complicated than it is. :)

OK, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
int b;
int c;

int max(int a, int b, int c) {
    
    if (a>b && a>c) {
        return a;
    }
    
    else if (b>a && b>c) {
        return b;
    }
    
    else {
        return c;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int d;
    d = max(44,8,16);
    
    if (d==a) {
        printf("a");
    }
    
    else if (d==b) {
        printf("b");
    }
    
    else {
        printf("c");
    }
}
```

It just shows me "c". Nothing else. What should I write in if functions in order to see "a", "b" and "c" characters according to return values in "max" function?

I want to keep max function as it is. So is it possible to do such a thing?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `a`, `b`, and `c` are uninitialized. What value do you think `a` or `b` have?

Comment: Move your global variables into main, assign them the values 44, 8, 16, and pass the variables to the function.

Comment: To simplify, how about: `int max(int a,int b,int c) { int ret = a; if (b > ret) ret = b; if (c > ret) ret = c; return ret; }` This is a bit more general and could easily be extended if we had: `int max(int a,int b,int c,int d) { ... }`

Comment: In your main function variables a, b, c have no value assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't assign any values to `a`, `b`, and `c`.  And since they're globals they're implicitly initialized to 0.  Note also that these globals are not the same as the parameters to `max` with the same name.  The paramaters *mask* the globals.

Move the globals into `main` and assign them values, then pass the variables to `max`.

```
int main()
{
    int a=48, b=8, c=16;
    int d;
    d = max(a,b,c);
    ...
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. After I try your solution, I also tried moving  `int a=48, b=8, c=16;` into global, and it also worked!